# Using C# within IIS7

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, scripting

I'm very new to IIS7 and somewhat new to C#. My project right now is to use C# and IIS7 to create an interactive website with various clickable items and features. The C# programs are written and working properly, however I honestly do not know much about IIS7 despite trying to research it for a good amount of time.

My question is, how do I integrate C# scripts into ISS7 so that the website can be hosted with said scripts running smoothly within it? In other words, how do I combine the powers of ISS7 and my C# code to make a website? What must I do within ISS7 to utilize my C# code?

I've already "created" my new site within IIS7 and given it the appropriate bindings. I'm just not sure where to go from here.

I realize this may be a broad question/answer, so pointing me to where information on this topic can be found would also be greatly appreciated. I've searched through the official IIS website without much luck. Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't you need ASP.NET to do this?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what kind of code you want to run. The best start might be a straight forward web project, and not web services/web api.

Create a new web site project in visual studio, and hook it up with IIS in `project properties-> web -> uncheck "Use IIS Express" and click "Create Virtual Directory"`. When you build the solution next time, it will be "deployed" to your local IIS.

[image: Project properties]

A virtual directory maps to a physical directory on a computer. The web application will be running on your machine. If you have IIS on a web server that is not your development machine, then you have to deploy your web application to this server. 
You might find this usefull: [How to: Create IIS Virtual Directories in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6cw6cfs(v=vs.100).aspx)

The relationship between Visual Studio and IIS is that you can create virtual directories from Visual Studio. This means that when you visit `localhost/MvcApplication1`, IIS serves you the web application that is mapped in `C:\Users\<Username>\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MvcApplication1`

Comment: ah okay. I guess I'm still figuring out how Visual Studio and IIS7 interact with eachother. So when I'm creating the virtual directory, what exactly do I put in that field within "project properties->web" in relation to my ISS7 site? Thanks a ton for your help.